# Instagram login with tor

Tags: python-3.x, tor

i am trying to login to instagram through tor
(i am using python3 on a linux machine if this helps!)
here is the code:

```
import json
import requests
import os
from colorama import Fore
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

def tor_session():
session = requests.session()
session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
return session

def login(username, password):
# params:
# [string]username- the username of the instagram account to log in to
# [string]password- the password to use in the log in process

# description:
# logs in to the account with the specified username and with the specified password

# session setup
sess = tor_session()
sess.cookies.update({
    'sessionid': '',
    'mid': '',
    'ig_pr': '1',
    'ig_vw': '1920',
    'csrftoken': '',
    's_network': '',
    'ds_user_id': ''
})
sess.headers.update({
    'UserAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36',
    'x-instagram-ajax': '1',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'origin': 'https://www.instagram.com',
    'ContentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com',
    'authority': 'www.instagram.com',
    'Host': 'www.instagram.com',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
})

# get csrftoken and the instagram main page
r = sess.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
sess.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': r.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']})

# log in
data = {'username': username, 'password': password}
r = sess.post('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/', data=data, allow_redirects=True)
token = r.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']
sess.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': token})

# parse the response from the log in
data = json.loads(r.text)
print(data)
if data['status'] == 'fail':
    return None
if data['authenticated']:
    return True
else:
    return False

login("username", "password")
```

the problem is that almost every time i have tried to run this
it didnt work and threw an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 156, in <module>
main()
File "main.py", line 152, in main
brute_force(username, pass_file_path)
File "main.py", line 114, in brute_force
logged_in = login(username, password)
File "main.py", line 81, in login
sess.headers.update({'X-CSRFToken': r.cookies.get_dict()['csrftoken']})
KeyError: 'csrftoken'
```

and sometimes it threw this exception:

```
File "main.py", line 94, in login
if data['authenticated']:
KeyError: 'authenticated'
```

how can i fix this?
i tried restarting tor
changing its configs
but nothing works
please help if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Instagram doesn't set cookies for tor users:

```
>>> s = your_setup_code_for_session()
>>> r = s.get('https://www.instagram.com')
>>> r.cookies.get_dict()
{}
```

I also tested this using the tor browser and got the same results:

[image]

It looks like you'll need to use a vpn or a Tor + vpn combination.

Comment: is there any way to it through tor only?

Comment: maybe proxy+tor or something

Comment: @asaf I don't think so, because [tor IP addresses are public knowledge](https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes)

Comment: @asaf proxy + tor should work though, if setup correctly.  As long as Instagram doesn't see a Tor IP you should be fine.

Comment: However, it's possible that they block certain vpn providers as well

Comment: do you know how to make this connection?

Comment: @asaf I haven't done it myself, but you can try [this guide](https://exposingtheinvisible.org/guides/vpn-over-tor).  If you can't figure out how to set it up, try asking on [Tor StackExchange](https://tor.stackexchange.com/).